# Text is cropped out

Tags: css

I was wondering why the text is cut-off at the bottom of the site? I am not sure where I have made a mistake but I think it is somewhere in The .wrapperTeam or below ;D

[Image of cropped text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGtTl.png)

CSS of that section:

```
#team {
  max-height: 920px;
  height: 100vp;
  background-color: #e7f1f8;
  text-align: center;
  h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: #3c4761;
    font-weight: 800;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .line {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #3c4761;
  }
  .wrapperTeam {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: 1fr;
    margin-top: 80px;
    h4 {
      font-size: 24px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-top: 40px;
    }
    .work {
      color: #30bae7;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
    p {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 300;
      width: 190px;
      margin: 30px auto 0 auto;

    }
    .social {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: and your HTML ?

Comment: increase your max height.

Comment: You have nested your selectors, which is not supported in native CSS. Are you using a preprocessor, like Sass or LESS? And could you provide a working example?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes I am using Sass
here is the code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpPwvL

Comment: If I delete overflow: hidden; in my container class than it is not cropping the text but I have a blank space between my sections

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I deleted height: 100vh; from my .container class and it works now!

Thanks guys for the interest, have a nice day!